# ListView Get All Child Views (On And Off Screen)

Tags: android

I am trying to iterate all child views of a listview including those that are off screen (invisible until scroll) but it only returns those that are onscreen (visible).

```
Button btnAddToCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
    btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View view;
            TextView tvProductBrand;
            for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++){

                view = lv.getChildAt(i);
                if(view != null)
                {
                    tvProductBrand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvProductBrand);
                    str_ItemBrand_from_lv = tvProductBrand.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lv_item: "+str_ItemBrand_from_lv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I know this `view = lv.getChildAt(i);` only returns visible views only, how can I return all child views?

My listview adapter is `lv_custom_adapter` (perhaps I need to use it instead but not sure how)?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

It's Good idea Use **RecyclerView**

gradle dependency:

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

put it in `NestedScrollView`
set `nestedScrollingEnabled=true`

```
<NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>
```

You will get all children at once

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post for shedding the light: [Get ListView children that are not in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463101/get-listview-children-that-are-not-in-view)

My view:

```
view = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, lv.getChildAt(i), lv);
```