# Enable and Disable Listview child that's not visible on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, children

I am trying to enable/disable items from a list view when a button is pressed using getChild function inside button callback. But i found that getChild function only returns the items that are visible.

```
ListView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(isEnabled);
```

Tried solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463101/get-listview-children-that-are-not-in-view). But unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's something that should be handled in the `Adapter`, not externally through the `View` hierarchy. What kind of `Adapter` are you using?

Comment: I am using ArrayAdaptor.....And this is how it looks ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.rooms_list_item, displayList);

Comment: OK, which exact effect are you wanting? That is, do you want the items not clickable? Or just grayed out? Or both?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about this before I left for a week. Hopefully, you got something figured out, but if not, [here's a basic example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10PWK6ByySQ2v4UBMRV_yO8cwBUhPdngC/view?usp=drivesdk) of a custom `Adapter` that disables every odd position, for a demo. You've to override `isEnabled()` in the `Adapter` to appropriately en/disable the `ListView`'s `OnItemClickListener`, if using one. Then you've to call `setEnabled()` appropriately on the `View` in `getView()` to get the proper visual style. Just text-replace `ArrayAdapter` in your code w/ `CustomAdapter`.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm not sure how you mean to handle setting each item, but [here's a quick example I threw together](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10dSH9smQfVgwxibKlvqm4eghC3teCZaS/view?usp=drivesdk) that let's you set each item disabled individually, without needing a custom class with a `boolean` for each object. The logic's kinda backwards, since the default state is enabled, so you're setting the _disabled_ state; e.g., `setItemDisabled(1, true)` disables position 1. Again, it's a drop-in replacement, so just change `ArrayAdapter` to `CustomAdapter` in your code. (Not fully tested, btw.)